# How do we know establishing a bijection between two infinite sets suffices to prove they have the same number of elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The method works for finite sets, but what proof do we have that the method extends for counting elements of infinte sets aswell? How do you justify that results obtained from using the method such as there are the same number of even numbers and all the natural numbers are correct?

Comment: That's how we *define* two sets to have the same number of elements.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, but if we look at the counter intuitive results we get from using this definition/technique, why do we keep on using it, and not come up with an alternative counting technique?

Comment: They are only counterintuitive because your intuition relies entirely on your experience with finite sets. Rather than the results being considered counterintuitive, they could instead be considered as demonstrations of the differences between finite sets and infinite sets. After all, the definition that we use to say two infinite sets have the same number of elements is the same definition we use for finite sets. Why would we have two different definitions?

Comment: @bakhtiar: Because it's useful. And we do have other counting techniques in other situations where they're useful: e.g. ordinal numbers to count the places in generalizations of sequences, or asymptotic density for measuring subsets of integers. Or geometric measures in geometric contexts like length, area, and volume, or more generally, measure theory.

Comment: You understand what a bijection *is*, right? It is a way of exactly matching up the elements of two sets. That's all. So it is the only really meaningful way of saying that the two sets contain the same "number" of elements. Note that it in no way requires you to state what this common "number" is.

Comment: What you're calling counter-intuitive (that a set can have the same number of elements as a proper subset) is the definition of an infinite set.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, Micheal Albanese gave you the correct answer in his comments, but actually I can show you **why** we define it that way. Assume there is a bijection f between 2 nonempty **finite** sets A and B. Assume B has one more element then A. Then since f is a bijection from A onto B, f is surjective onto B. But that means since there is one more element in B then A, there must be at least 1 element in A which has 2 different values in the range B. But then f is not one to one and we have a contradiction. Also, if f is one to one,then every element x of A has a corresponding unique element f(x) in B.But by assumption, B has one more element of A.Therefore,B has one more element then Range (f). But then f is not onto B and we again have a contradiction. The exact same argument with the inverse function f produces the same contradictions for f-1 from B onto A.

So A and B must have the same number of elements if f:A --->B is bijective. That answer your question? Happy holidays!

Addenda: Goos has critized me to the hilt that this argument only applies to finite sets-for infinite sets, the argument doesn't hold. Ok,fair enough-but it **does** convey the basic idea why it's so.

Comment: My fan club. Sigh.

Comment: What in the world does it mean for one infinite set to have "one more element" than another?  Do you mean $A \subset B$ and $|B \setminus A| = 1$?

Comment: I am pretty sure this answer is nonsense.

Comment: @Goos No,it's not nonsense.Apparently the OP didn't agree with you. And yes-the complement of A with respect to B is a singleton. Sorry this wasn't clear in the answer.

Comment: Sorry @Mathemagician, your answer is (still) wrong.  You do know that if $|B \setminus A| = 1$ for infinite $A, B$ then they in fact have equal cardinality?  You cannot derive a contradiction from $|B \setminus A| = 1$ (i.e. from "Assume $B$ has one more element than $A$") because this statement in fact holds in all infinite cases.  Your flawed assumption is that the number of elements that one set has "more" than another set is a well-defined quantity, when in fact it could be literally any finite number or even an infinite cardinality.

Comment: You really need to go back and do a basic review of cardinality.  The entire reason mathematicians *developed* cardinality was to deal with the following problem: for infinite sets $A, B$ it is no longer meaningful to say one has "one more" element than the other, or "two more" elements, or any number of elements more than the other, or vice versa.

Comment: @Goos My only mistake with my intuitive argument for the OP was not insisting the sets be finite.that would have been more then sufficient to make the case. I tried to be too clever and ended up looking like an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

The "size" of a set defines an ordering relationship.
You want your definition of that ordering relationship to have properties we commonly expect in an ordering relationship:

- If $a < b$ and $b < c$ then $a < c$
- Defining  "$a = b$" as the statement that neither $a<b$ nor $b<a$ holds, you want "=" to be transitive.

There is a sense in which (for example) the "number of" perfect squares of integers is "less than" the "number of" integers.  But say you defined  for sets $A,B$ that $N(A) < N(B) \Longleftrightarrow A \subset B$. Then the first of the two desired properties holds, but the second does not.

It turns out to be hard to come up with a suitable definition of the number of a set being less than that of another set, that is materially different than the bijection definition.

Comment: That is a horrible way to define equality. It also fails entirely without the axiom of choice when there are incomparable cardinals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right and it's a good example of how intuition can fail us sometimes in mathematics.